# Prevent line breaks in ES6 template string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

ESLint: Line 403 exceeds the maximum line length of 120 (max-len)

I have a long string, which I built using ES6 template strings, but I want it to be without line breaks:

```
var string = `Let me be the 'throws Exception’ to your 'public static void 
              main (String[] args)’. I will accept whatever you give me my ${love}.`
console.log(string);
```

Result:

```
 Let me be the 'throws Exception’ to your 'public static void 
 main (String[] args)’. I will accept whatever you give me xxx.
```

My expectation:

```
Let me be the 'throws Exception’ to your 'public static void main (String[] args)’. I will accept whatever you give me xxx.
```

**Requirements**:

1. I cannot disable the eslint rule, as enforcement is necessary.
2. I cannot put the data in a separate file, as the data is dynamic.
3. I cannot concatenate multiple shorter strings, since that is too much work.

Comment: If you don't want linebreaks, don't write any?

Comment: ESLint: Line 403 exceeds the maximum line length of 120 (max-len)

Comment: `myStr.replace("\n","");`

Comment: `string.replace(/\r|\n/g, "")`, but you also seem to want `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")`

Comment: looking for something more clean, cant I tag and denote?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal a) disable that rule if you don't care b) put large data in a separate file not in your code c) Use multiple strings (e.g. one for every sentence) and just concatenate them

Comment: a) disable that rule if you don't care  - Enforcement is needed.

Comment: b) put large data in a separate file not in your code: not possible as I can create string on fly.

Comment: c) Use multiple strings (e.g. one for every sentence) and just concatenate them : Looks too much of a work after using  short and sweet syntax of string templates

Comment: Ragarding `c`, it's sweet but doesn't work as you expect. It's possible to make it transform a string with custom tag function. See the update.

Comment: So, "enforcement is needed" for a rule you don't want to enforce? You know that you can disable a rule for just that line, right?

Comment: correct, I know that but I don't want to add two extra lines everytime I have to use this functionality.

Comment: Can you change the rule instead? It has https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len#ignoretemplateliterals as an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. One of the important problems that template literals solve is [multiline strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings):

> Any new line characters inserted in the source are part of the template literal.

If the string needs to be processed further, this can be done with other JS features, like regular expressions:

```
var string = `Let me be the 'throws Exception’ to your 'public static void 
              main (String[] args)’. I will accept whatever you give me.`
              .replace(/[\n\r]+ */g, ' ');
```

[`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) is built-in function to transform template literals. It's possible to use tag function to provide custom behaviour to template literals. It should be noticed that `String.raw` differs from default template transformer in terms of how it processes [special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/special-characters-javascript#escape-sequences). If they are used in a string, they should be additionally processed with [`unescape-js`](https://github.com/iamakulov/unescape-js/blob/master/src/index.js#L35-L49) or similar helper function.

```
function singleLine(strsObj, ...values) {
  const strs = strsObj.raw
  .map(str => str.replace(/[\n\r]+ */g, ' '))
  .map(unescapeSpecialChars);
  return String.raw(
    {raw: strs },
    ...values
  );
}


var string = singleLine`Let me be the 'throws Exception’ to your 'public static void 
              main (String[] args)’. I will accept whatever you give me.`;
```

Comment: No, `String.raw` means something else. Consider the difference between `\`\"\`` and `String.raw\`\"\``.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for noticing that. I was aware of the fact that it works like that with template strings, so yes, it makes sense that it behaves like that when being called directly too. Do you have ideas how default transformer can be reliably recreated by chance?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Yes, `oneLine` is pretty much close to the one that was listed in the answer. It depends if it needs to be customized further, e.g. how multiple line breaks should be treated.

Answer (score 4):

A good way of reaching your purpose is to to join an array of strings:

```
var string = [
  `Let me be the 'throws Exception’ to your 'public static void`,
  `main (String[] args)’. I will accept whatever you give me my ${love}.`
].join(' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is just the EsLint error you can ignore it for this specific line using this feature: `/* eslint-disable max-len */`

In my honest opinion is the best approach because you are not giving extra complexity.

If you start using regex or concatenation you are changing the purpose of template string by not using concatenation...

Comment: How can I just enable it for a line?

Comment: /* eslint-disable max-len */ Line /* eslint-enable max-len */ ??

Comment: this looks like an addition of two extra line whenever I need to do something like this

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal *How can I just enable it for a line* By reading the documentation? The syntax is `// eslint-disable-line max-len`.

Answer (score 2):

Use string concatenation as well:

```
var string=`abc`+`def`;
console.log(string);
```

yields:

`abcdef`