# Inserting a new line into a template string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I've tried splitting it into two lines:

```
const templateString = `this is my template 
                        string`
```

And I've also tried:

```
const templateString = `this is my template\n string`
```

But none of these work. The `templateString` still comes out as one line. How do you create multi-line template string?

Comment: your [first syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings) should work.

Comment: You mean to render it on the client side as HTML? That would require a <br> tag. Your first attempt is the correct one, if you add the <br> tag.

Comment: Multiline is [the expected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379197/3731501), it's line breaks removal that will require special treatment.

Comment: both syntaxes are working. How do you output `templateString`?

Comment: @scraaappy I'm outputting it inside an html element - `div` or `p` tag

Comment: @user3492940 Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. Adding the `<br />` inside the template string worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it was what you looked for (:

Answer (score -6, accepted):

That would require a `<br>` tag. Your first attempt is the correct one, if you add the `<br>` tag.

Comment: that just shows up as 
```this is my template <br> string```
that doesn't actually break the line

Comment: Same as above comment

Comment: @ enf0rcer Please show an example of how that answer solves the problem.